# Dynamically parsing the Ethereum logs returned from FilterLogs function

Tags: go-ethereum, golang, type-casting

I am trying to parse the logs of a contract in a fully dynamic manner. Meaning that the only thing I have is the abi of the contract, and the filter query to filter out logs. I would like to parse the returned events dynamically. Here is my attempt so far:

```
func (c *Client) getHistoricalEvents(abiStr string, filterQuery ethereum.FilterQuery) ([]map[string]any, error) {
    contractAbi, err := abi.JSON(strings.NewReader(abiStr))
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    logs, err := c.client.FilterLogs(c.ctx, filterQuery)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    
    var events []map[string]any
    for _, log := range logs {
        event := map[string]any{}
        for _, evInfo := range contractAbi.Events {
            if evInfo.ID.Hex() != log.Topics[0].Hex() {
                continue
            }

            if err := contractAbi.UnpackIntoMap(event, evInfo.Name, log.Data); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }

            indexedArgCount := 0
            for _, arg := range evInfo.Inputs {
                if arg.Indexed {
                    // i + 1 index due to first topic being function signature
                    indexedArgCount += 1
                    event[arg.Name] = log.Topics[indexedArgCount].Hex()
                }
            }

            break
        }

        events = append(events, event)
    }

    return events, nil
}
```

What I am doing above as steps is simply following:

1. Convert and validate that the provided abi is valid
2. Filter logs by the provided filter query
3. Iterate over returned logs
4. Find which event signature matches the log
5. Unpack the log.Data into map, as stated in the docs, this only unpacks the unindexed arguments
6. Range over the input arguments, and add indexed arguments to the map as well

There is one thing I want to do. In the loop where I range over the arguments to add the indexed variables into map as well, I add the variables as hex values. I would much prefer if I was able to get the type of the value and do a proper conversion, and set it to the map that way. I see that type Argument has `Type.GetType()` function which returns reflect.Type, but I am not sure how can I utilize that.

Thanks for any type of help!